# Sorting relational tables using only 1 field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, join, sql-order-by

I have 2 relational tables and I joined them, and I want it to be sorted by the same field.

Tables:

posts fields: id, post, created

reposts fields: id,post_id, created

Here's what I currently have:

```
SELECT 
p.post as post,
p.created as post_created,
rp.created as repost_created
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN reposts rp
ON rp.post_id = p.id
ORDER BY rp.created DESC, p.created DESC
```

And here's the result of that code:

{[image: Code Result][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZbnL.png)

But what I want is to sort the whole data, base on the ***created*** field as a whole, regarding if it has repost_created or if it's null, it will base on the post_created field. Like this:

[[image: Desired Result][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7l8r.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't display p.id or rp.post_id in either image, but you probably need to include both in your `order by` clause. e.g. `order by coalece(rp.post_id, p.id)` then other columns. If you supplied sample data in your question (in text, per table, not a query result) then perhaps we could do more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) the value of `rp.created` with `p.created` and sort on that; that way if `rp.created` is not NULL you'll sort on that date, otherwise you'll sort on `p.created`:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(rp.created, p.created) DESC
```

Note that you may want an additional criterion to break ties (when two rows have the same datetime value), you could perhaps use

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(rp.created, p.created) DESC, rp.id IS NULL
```

this will sort reposts ahead of posts at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I want. Sorry if my question is not that clear, but thank you for the effort of understanding my question and answering it 

Answer (score 0):

i think your purpose is

```
SELECT 
p.post as post,
p.created as post_created,
rp.created as repost_created
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN reposts rp
ON rp.post_id = p.id
ORDER BY  isnull( p.created ,rp.created)
```